# Interpolation content on html is coming in string format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interpolation

Angular Version 1.4

So I have this code
**html**

```
 <div>{{ isConditionTrue() ? '<p>Some content<p>' : '<p>some other content</p>'}}</div>
```

**component.js**

```
$scope.isCondition = function(){
    return true;// lets say.
}
```

But on UI the whole interpolation is coming in string  as

```
 <div>"{{ isConditionTrue() ? '<p>Some content<p>' : '<p>some other content</p>'}}"</div>
```

**Update**:

The values are sometimes string and sometimes html . So how to make it generic.
Someone help!!!    T_T

Comment: are you using `isConditionTrue` or `isCondition`? Also to render HTML you should use `<div ng-bind-html="..."></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-bind-html`.

**View**

```
 <div ng-bind-html="isConditionTrue()"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.isConditionTrue = function() {
   if (true) {
     return '<p>IF content<p>';
   } else {
     return '<p>ELSE content<p>';
  }
}
```

Let me know if you are facing any problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you need to use **ng-bind-html** directive with the help of **ngSanitize** library, which helps you to render the html in safe way.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.isCondition = function(){return true;}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="isCondition() ? '<p>Some content</p>' : '<p>Some other content</p>'">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```